# Why did Ymir die after being pierced by a spear, if she should have the regenerative powers of a Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In one of the last episodes of the anime of Attack on Titan, we see a flashback where Ymir is pierced by a spear, and because of this she dies. But by then she had the powers of the titans, so she should be able to regenerate her wounds.

Why did Ymir die after being pierced by a spear, if she should have the regenerative powers of a Titan?

Answer (score 1):

Ymir Fritz died because she wanted to. If you look closely at the relevant anime scene, when Ymir first fell down after being struck by the spear, her eyes were open.
[image]
She wanted to see whether King Fritz would now see her as more than a slave, given that she had just taken a spear for him. However, King Fritz immediately refers to her as a slave again.
[image]
That leaves her with no more reason to go on living, so she decides not to heal herself at that moment (indicated by her closing her eyes), resulting in her death.
[image]